# Python string.rstrip() doesn't strip specified characters

Tags: python, strip

```
string = "hi())("
string = string.rstrip("abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxyz")
print(string)
```

I want to remove every letter from given string using rstrip method, however it does not change the string in the slightest.

Output:

```
'hi())('
```

What i Want:

```
'())('
```

I know that I can use regex, but I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

Note : It is a part of the Valid Parentheses challenge on code-wars

Comment: You need `strip` to strip from the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `lstrip` instead of `rstrip`:

```
>>> string = "hi())("
>>> string = string.lstrip("abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxyz")
>>> string
'())('
```